# Skobbler 2.5.1 on Android occasionally routes to viaPoints incorrectly.

Tags: android, skmaps

I have an example route that I've tested using the Skobbler SDK.

**Start Point**: around 820 S MacArthur Blvd
Irving, TX 75063
**End Point**: Bass Performance Hall, Fort Worth, TX
**Via Point #1**: Shell Gas Station, 1224 Oakland Blvd Fort Worth, TX

The code that's used to calculate the route is as follows:

```
SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();
// set start and destination points
route.setStartCoordinate(start);
route.setDestinationCoordinate(end);
route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
// set the route mode
route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
// Traffic enabled
route.setUseLiveTraffic(true);
route.setUseLiveTrafficETA(true);

route.setTollRoadsAvoided(true);
route.setAvoidFerries(true);
route.setHighWaysAvoided(true);

ArrayList<SKViaPoint> viaPoints = new ArrayList<SKViaPoint>();
viaPoints.add(new SKViaPoint(VIA_POINT_ID_OTW_DEST, viaPoint));
route.setViaPoints(viaPoints);
// set whether the route should be shown on the map after it's computed
route.setRouteExposed(true);
// Set traffic routing mode
SKRouteManager.getInstance().setTrafficRoutingMode(SKMapSettings.SKTrafficMode.FLOW_AND_INCIDENTS);
// set the route listener to be notified of route calculation
// events
SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(this);
// pass the route to the calculation routine
SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);
```

When I compute this route via the Skobbler SDK and display the calculated route on the SKMapView, I sometimes get a route that doesn't make sense.

[image: Incorrect Routing Example]
This route calculated on one of our test devices shows the calculated route taking us off the freeway, turning right onto a street and then making a u-turn at the end of the street, before turning right again into the Shell gas station. For some reason, the routing algorithm is not realizing that the route can go straight off the freeway and then turn right, or alternatively, turn right at the street off the freeway and then make an immediate left.

This is not the only instance of incorrect routing that we have witnessed, but it is the most recent. In the past, we have been able to make slight modifications to the coordinate passed for the via point to make the routing algorithm return a sensible route, and then were able to go back to recalculating the original route correctly without the long detours.

In this case, in order to view the corrected route below, we simply try routing the same route again some time later:

[image: corrrect routing example]

Has anyone experienced an issue similar to this and is there something that can be done on the client side to prevent it? Or perhaps a request setting that can be made while requesting a route calculation to the server that might help?

Thanks for any feedback on the matter!
-Keith

Comment: question reported to the Scout developers

Comment: Hi @SylviA, any update yet? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Keith, not yet :(

Comment: Hi @SylviA, just wanted to see if there was any feedback on this issue, thanks!

Comment: For 2.5.1 no update, but please check if this behavior is still present in the latest 3.0 build: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7651-Android-3-0-beta-build-update-28-06-2016

Comment: any feedback on this, me too facing the same issue for 2.5